# PHP Save outgoing php mail messages

Tags: php, email

What is the best way to save a record of outgoing mail through the PHP mail function?

Basically, I want to archive the messages like the Sent folder in Thunderbird/Outlook.

The only 2 options I can think of is create a DB field, or save them at txt files on the server.

I was wondering if anybody had any suggestions, or methods I might be over looking

Answer (score 3):

Either make a copy of the mail and store it yourself in your mailing script, or... and this one's quite handy: BCC a copy of the email to whatever account you want to be the archive of the sent messages. You can set up a mail folder rule to redirect those BCC'd copies into a specific folder if need be.

Comment: I think this method would be the best for the quick fix I'm trying to do. Thanks for all the other suggestions, MongoDB looks great, and the SQL has its benifits but this will probably be the best for my application..Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest saving them in database since it makes searching them a lot easier than plain text files

Answer (score 0):

If there is a massive amount of mail look into MongoDB. It is a NoSQL DB and many sites use it for archival purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would save them in a database. When the emailer runs to send out messages, a copy is added to the database. You can also keep track when the email was sent and all that fun information. It will make searching the database easier later. Text files would be a pain, imo.